# trying to use Powershell to look in an OU in active directory for computers to see if they specific software

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm still pretty new to PowerShell, and am still learning how to use it. I saw I could use a cmdlet named Get-WmiObject, but I'm not sure that's the right one to use. I've seen people saying when using it that it might throw up errors on the user-end, which would confuse users.

So digging around, people are saying I can query the registry of all the computers in an OU, which would search here "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" and possibly here "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall". The problem I'm running into is I'm not sure which cmdlet to start out using (if a cmdlet at all), how to tell it to search in that specific registry, while also telling it to go through each computer in an OU checking.

I need to search for all computers that have "Microsoft Office" installed. Can anyone point me in the right direction? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: use `Invoke-Command` to run a scriptblock on each target system. test the scriptblock locally until it works and then use it in an I-C call against your local system. next, use a known-good system name. _finally_ [*grin*] , use a list of systems to run against in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get a list of computer names in the OU and for that you need to get the `DistinghuishedName` property of that OU. (look in ADUC -> OU Properties -> Attributes -> DistinghuishedName)

Using that, you can use the function below to test for installed software:

```
function Get-InstalledSoftware {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [string]$NamePattern = '*',

        [switch]$ExcludeUpdates
    )
    begin {
        $UninstallPaths = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\',
                          'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\'
    }
    process {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($computer) -or $computer -eq '.') { $computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME }

            # if the computername is its SamAccountName, it ends in a dollar sign.
            $computer = $computer -replace '\$$', ''

            if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
                Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' cannot be reached."
                continue
            }

            $system  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer
            $baseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$computer)
            foreach ($regPath in $UninstallPaths) {
                $key = $baseKey.OpenSubKey($regPath)
                # if the key exists
                if ($key) {
                    $key.GetSubKeyNames() | ForEach-Object {
                        $subKey      = $baseKey.OpenSubKey("$regPath$_")
                        $application = $subKey.GetValue('DisplayName')
                        if (($application) -and ($application -like $NamePattern)) {
                            if (!$ExcludeUpdates -or ($application -notlike "*update*")) {
                                [PSCustomObject]@{
                                    'Computer'        = $system.Name
                                    'Application'     = $application
                                    'Version'         = $subKey.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                                    'InstallLocation' = $subKey.GetValue('InstallLocation')
                                    'UninstallString' = $subKey.GetValue('UninstallString')
                                    'Publisher'       = $subKey.GetValue('Publisher')
                                    'LoggedOnUser'    = $system.UserName
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        # close $subKey
                        if ($subKey)  { $subKey.Close() }
                    }
                    # close $key
                    if ($key)  { $key.Close() }
                }
            }
            # close $baseKey
            if ($baseKey)  { $baseKey.Close() }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Note: if you have PowerShell 3.0 or better, you can change the line `$system  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer` into `$system  = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer -Verbose:$false` which will perform faster</sup>

Use it like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$OuDn = 'DistinghuishedName of the OU you are interested in'

# get a list of computer names in the given OU
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OuDn | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# use the function to get a list of installed applicationa
$software = Get-InstalledSoftware -ComputerName $computers -NamePattern "Microsoft Office*" -ExcludeUpdates

# output to console or export to a CSV file
$software | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\software.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>Note: this function does all the work on your pc, so you must make sure you are running it as a user that has permission to read the registry keys on all of the machines.</sup>

<sup>Also, in order for a key to be opened remotely, both the server and client machines must be running the **remote registry service**, and have remote administration enabled.</sup>

Comment: You've been -extremely- helpful. I have only 1 more issue. Looking through it after running it, for some reason it doesn't look like it can reach any of the computers. I get the error as if none of the PCs are live. An example: WARNING: Computer 'name$' cannot be reached." Should it have the $ at the end?

Comment: @br34k Ouch.. sorry, my mistake. I forgot computer SamAccountNames end with a `$` to distinghuish them from user SamAccountNames..
Please see my updated version.

Comment: That's something i should have found myself i think. Sorry about that. But i am still running into errors having searching around to no avail...

Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found.

$baseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey <<<< ([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$computer)
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException


You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
$key = $baseKey.OpenSubKey <<<< ($regPath)
FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

is there anything i can do for this?

Comment: @br34k The 2nd error is the result of the 1st one. Because `Test-Connection` seems to work, does RemoteRegistry using RegEdit work? Is the Remote Registry service running on the remote computers? Try `(Get-Service -ComputerName RemotePC1 -Name RemoteRegistry).Status`. If it is stopped, try and start it using `Get-Service -ComputerName RemotePC1 -Name RemoteRegistry | Start-Service`. In order for a key to be opened remotely, both the server and client machines must be running the remote registry service, and have remote administration enabled. Another cause could be a firewall issue.

Comment: Thank you again, i wish i could hug you haha. It seems the service is disabled on practically all of the PCs I'm trying to check. We're going to work on a group policy soon to turn the remoteregistry on for the computers soon and hopefully go positively from there. Thanks for all of your assistance!