# Get -ADComputer (retrieve all installed software on all desktops on domain)

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and have recently found out that it can query information from multiple computers at once. This beats having to go to each computer on the domain. What I want is a list of all software installed on all computers with the computer name associated with each list or each software. I found this snip it that i thought might work, but I am getting errors.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*"} | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer $_.Name}
```

This is the error that I am getting. I am not to sure what is my syntax error or if this will even produce the data that I need.

> Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: 'OperatingSystem -NotLike
>   "*server*”' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '26'. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*server*”} | ForEac ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADFilterParsingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to use Powershell to look in an OU in active directory for computers to see if they specific software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622860/trying-to-use-powershell-to-look-in-an-ou-in-active-directory-for-computers-to-s)

Comment: First try simplifying your query, leave out piping into ForEach.  Do you still get the error?  I've tested this command:  Get-ADComputer -Properties OperatingSystem -Filter {OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Pro*"} | FL Name,OperatingSystem   and it returns all servers on my domain.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running?  What is the OS of the machine on which you're running the commands?  I've run your code on Windows 10 1809 against a Windows 2019 domain controller using Windows PowerShell v5.1 and it worked as expected.  is this a standalone command or part of a script?

Comment: @RichardSiddaway I do not know what happen, but I tried it today and it just worked. I am not sure what was causing my error before, but it is working now. It turns out it was right the first time